# How do I get my pet unstuck?

Tags: torchlight-2

I've only been playing Torchlight 2 for a couple of hours and I have seen my pet get stuck twice already, and both times in fishing holes. I find that walking away from my pet gets him unstuck after some distance, but that would mean roaming around alone for a while, which is not a good idea for some classes.

Is there a more reliable way to get a pet unstuck and immediately?

Comment: Could try sending it to town. It wouldn't save *much* time though.

Comment: Tangential: you're going to have trouble if your pet is functioning as much more than a pack mule. I personally just learnt to live with my pet dealing with the occasional baddie when it felt like it, but mostly just staring at me fighting a horde from a ledge.

Comment: Your pet is unreliable - don't make a build that relies on it.

Comment: Noted and thanks for the tips. Although I don't personally rely on my pet right now (I'm playing a berserker), I just feel _naked_ without my panda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*One workaround would be to get items and/or skills that drastically reduce pet town travel time, (eg. [Rohac's boots](http://torchlight2armory.com/item?i=-7007297487581673875)) and just send your pet to town whenever it gets stuck. You can find a list of items that possess this attribute [here](http://torchlight2armory.com/items?f=100&fe=g&fo=0).

*EDIT: As pointed out by jw013, it is not necessary to reduce pet travel time at all. You can simply send your pet to town and recall it immediately.

Comment: You can recall your pet when sending it to town to get it to instantly reappear.

Comment: @jw013 Ah yes, that's true. Haven't played in a while.

Comment: @Asad Edit that answer! ;3